# How do I initialize an EntitySet wrapped in a getter/setter using object initializers in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql

I am adapting the [Windows Phone Database Example using MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for my own app. Here it suggests wrapping the `EntitySet` properties on the model objects with a getter/setter combination that allows assignment using an `IEnumerable` (using the `Assign` method) e.g.

```
// Example method from a model class 'SomeModelObject'
[Association(Storage = "_todos", OtherKey = "_categoryId", ThisKey = "Id")]
public EntitySet<ToDoItem> ToDos
{
    get { return this._todos; }
    set { this._todos.Assign(value); }
}
```

However when I try and instantiate an object that has an `EntitySet` property it will not allow it, e.g.

```
SomeModelObject myModelObject = new SomeModelObject() {
    Property1 = "foo",
    Property2 = true,
    // Following raises an error, even though setter should allow assignment
    // from an IEnumerable (because of the use of 'Assign' in the setter)
    ToDos = new List<ToDoItem>() {
        new ToDoItem(),
    },
};
```

The error is as follows,

```
Error    1   Cannot implicitly convert type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<SomeApp.ToDoItem>' to 
'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<SomeApp.ToDoItem>'
```

How do I instantiate objects referenced from an `EntitySet`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are two problems with the code you've posted.

I suspect the main problem is that you're *trying* to set the value of the property to a `List<ToDoItem>` when the type of the property is `EntitySet<ToDoItem>`. (The error message you've posted doesn't match the code you've posted, but never mind.) You say it "should allow assignment from an `IEnumerable`, but I don't know why you'd expect that to be the case, given the declaration of the property:

```
public EntitySet<ToDoItem> ToDos { ... }
```

The property is *not* of type `IEnumerable<ToDoItem>`.

You're *also* using `new SomeModelObject` twice for some reason:

```
SomeModelObject myModelObject = new SomeModelObject() {
    new SomeModelObject() {
        Property1 = "foo",
        ...
    }
};
```

I'll assume your *real* code looks more like this:

```
SomeModelObject myModelObject = new SomeModelObject() {
  Property1 = "foo",
  ... 
};
```

Please be more careful in future - it's very hard to diagnose code that isn't posted.

There are three options around the `EntitySet`.

If you want to add new items to an *existing* `EntitySet<ToDoItem>` you can do that within the object initializer:

```
SomeModelObject myModelObject = new SomeModelObject {
  Property1 = "foo",
  Property2 = true,
  ToDos = {
    new ToDoItem(),
  }
};
```

Alternatively, if you want to set the value of the property itself, you need to create a new `EntitySet<ToDoItem>`:

```
SomeModelObject myModelObject = new SomeModelObject {
  Property1 = "foo",
  Property2 = true,
  ToDos = new EntitySet<ToDoItem> {
    new ToDoItem(),
  }
};
```

This seems unlikely to be a good idea though, and I'd actually suggest making the setter private.

Alternatively, if you really want to be able to assign any `IEnumerable<ToDoItem>`, you can just change the type of the property:

```
[Association(Storage = "_todos", OtherKey = "_categoryId", ThisKey = "Id")]
public IEnumerable<ToDoItem> ToDos
{
    get { return this._todos; }
    set { this._todos.Assign(value); }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, yes you are right, I have adjusted the code to try and get the simplest case - I've updated the question. Secondly the reason why I thought you could assign an IEnumerable to the Entity set is because of the setter which uses `Assign` and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299765.aspx this accepts an IEnumerable.

Comment: @Brendan: `Assign` accepts an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, but that's not the type of the property, is it? The use of `Assign` is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Ok that's brilliant, it compiles now using the typed `EntitySet`, however if I am creating a new object, under what conditions would the `ToDos` property be pre-existing?

Comment: @Brendan: If the constructor for the containing object creates it? (As it does in the sample code you were looking at...)